# Bamboo CLI 'getTaskList' error

Tags: command-line-interface, bamboo

I am trying to get the list of tasks inside a job. I ran a command as `D:\bamboo-cli-5.5.0\bamboo.bat --action getTaskList --job "BAM-PLAN-JOB1" --server "http://localhost:8085" --user "abc" --password "***"` 
I am getting an error as `Client error: Invalid action specified: GETTASKLIST.  Use --help for more information.`
Is there any way to rectify this error ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using Version 5.5 of the Bob Swift CLI the "getTaskList" command was not added until version 6.1. Upgrade the plugin and grab the new shell scripts from Bob Swift.